# how to add title, message,buttons to ng-dialog in angular js as we do in JQuery prompt

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, prompt, ng-dialog

I am using  https://github.com/likeastore/ngDialog#api for [Ng Dialog](https://github.com/likeastore/ngDialog#api).

I wanted to show a dialog box with the title, message, and the buttons to display.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You must define them explicitly. The doc you pointed has directives for the buttons. The only "built in" button is the chance to add a Close. However Title and so must be added by hand.

Comment: You Can create your own template, and use it: https://github.com/likeastore/ngDialog#template-string

Answer (score 2):

With ng-dialog you can use your own created template(with title buttons, messages) etc.. https://github.com/likeastore/ngDialog#template-string

For example:

```
 ngDialog.openConfirm({template: "<h3>Title<h3> ..."})
```

or you could use templateCache to make code clean: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache

```
$templateCache.put('my-template.html', "html");    
ngDialog.openConfirm({template: 'my-template.html'})
```